# Is there a faster way to do for loop in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

my user case is to check if a client (account) has already bought somthing in the same magasin (store) during the last 30 days , if yes, then save the times that he has bought in this magasin in the new columns [HAS_BOUGHT_30_DAYS_AGO]
For example the dataframe i have is like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-07-20','2019-07-29','2019-07-03','2019-08-20','2019-08-24','2019-08-05','2019-07-07','2019-06-23'],'account':['0410','0412','0410','0410','0412','0410','0410','0410'],'store':['amazon','carrefour','amazon','zara','carrefour','carrefour','auchan','amazon']})
```

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

```
    date       account  store
0   2019-07-20  0410    amazon
1   2019-07-29  0412    carrefour
2   2019-07-03  0410    amazon
3   2019-08-20  0410    zara
4   2019-08-24  0412    carrefour
5   2019-08-05  0410    carrefour
6   2019-07-07  0410    auchan
7   2019-06-23  0410    amazon
```

And my methode to do this is:

```
for transaction in df.itertuples():
    delta=transaction.date-df.date
    trans_before=df.loc[(df.account== transaction.account) & (delta.dt.days>0) & (delta.dt.days<30) &(df.store== transaction.store)]
    df.loc[transaction.Index,'HAS_BOUGHT_30_DAYS_AGO']= len(trans_before)
```

and i got the result:

```
    date        account store    HAS_BOUGHT_30_DAYS_AGO
0   2019-07-20  0410    amazon      2.0
1   2019-07-29  0412    carrefour   0.0
2   2019-07-03  0410    amazon      1.0
3   2019-08-20  0410    zara        0.0
4   2019-08-24  0412    carrefour   1.0
5   2019-08-05  0410    carrefour   0.0
6   2019-07-07  0410    auchan      0.0
7   2019-06-23  0410    amazon      0.0
```

This methode works but it cost to much time for my big dataset (i have 14837843 lines) anybody has a faster solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort the values of dataframe on column `date`. Then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on columns `account, store` and transform the column `date` using custom lambda function `f`:

```
f = lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.cumsum().between(0, 30).cumsum()
df['HAS_BOUGHT'] = df.sort_values('date').groupby(['account', 'store'])['date'].apply(f)
```

**Result:**

```
        date account      store  HAS_BOUGHT
0 2019-07-20    0410     amazon           2
1 2019-07-29    0412  carrefour           0
2 2019-07-03    0410     amazon           1
3 2019-08-20    0410       zara           0
4 2019-08-24    0412  carrefour           1
5 2019-08-05    0410  carrefour           0
6 2019-07-07    0410     auchan           0
7 2019-06-23    0410     amazon           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `df.loc` which effectively does a cartesian product over your dataframe. It iterates entire dataframe for each row, meaning that time complexity is effectively O(n^2). So as your data grows, not only it slows down the for loop, but every slowdown gets slower too.

To make such queries more efficient, you might want to build an index on `(account, date)`, or sort your records accordingly. I am assuming that there are many more transactions than accounts, so this would narrow down the space that you have to search to a single account, plus reduce seeks to O(log n). I'm not sure how to do that in Pandas, but if your memory allows it, you can simply use Python lists and dictionaries.

Another way would be to store the data in a relational database and use SQL for querying (after creating the index of course).